# no match for operator>> with operand types ifstream and double

Tags: c++

I have a problem with operator overloading.
I have a class named `Point1`, which is defined as

```
class Point1 {
private:
    long double x;
public:
    Point1(): x(0) {}
    Point1(long double val): x(val) {}
    Point1(Point1 & val): x(val.x) {}
    //Some functions omitted
    friend ofstream& operator<< (ofstream&, const Point1&);
    friend ifstream& operator>> (ifstream&, Point1&);
};
```

The class is working, exept for the `operator>>(ifstream&, Point1&);`,  whose function body is:

```
double tmp;
in >> tmp; //In this line g++ breaks with an error
pnt.x=tmp;
return in;
```

I am using gcc 4.9.3 on debian testing (armv7l).
The complete sourcecode can be found here: http://hastebin.com/igunaquxiw.cpp

Comment: And we're alll supposed to know what `in` is?

Comment: No errors posted, no [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), -1.

Comment: in is ifstream& and pnt is Point1&

Comment: Fwiw, change your functions (including friend declarations)  to use `std::istream&` and `std::ostream&`. And kindly flesh out the near-mcve you're so-close to having.

Comment: @RobertWadowski No, the function is friend.

Comment: I am having `using namespace std;` right beyond the include. @WhozCraig that didnt fix it. cin >> doubleVar; works though.

Comment: @songyuanyao Sorry I misunderstood, I thought Morten is using it somewhere else

Comment: Do you have included iostream?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Your "complete" linked source code doesn't include `<fstream>`. And you're still going to want to do what I described earlier. The ones you said didn't work? Welll, [See it live](http://ideone.com/pCHOic).

Comment: @WhozCraig I said it won't work and keep my opinion, seeing this live looks like you fixed problem :). For me there is difference between ifstream and istream :)

Comment: @RobertWadowski "that didnt fix it" - didnt' sound like an opinion. The difference between `std::ifstream` and `std::istream` is significant. Formatted  insertion and extraction operators are designed for the latter. If you've specific reasons *not* to go with the latter it is feasible formatted operators aren't on the menu. Regardless, an *outstanding* Q&A on operator overloading [can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading), including formatted insertion and extraction. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig  Indeed worth of reading, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have overloaded stream operators for files but you are not using files I/O but console input.

```
cin >> pnt >> pnt2;
```

Change to

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, const Point1& p)
{
    s << p.x;
    return s;
}
friend istream& operator>> (istream& s, Point1& p)
{
    s >> p.x;
    return s;
}
```

If you compare types here there is wrong type overloaded for cin operation, some info
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream

Cin is of type istream but there is no operator for this type, there is only operator for ifstream.

Answer (score 3):

Your code expects `ofstream` and `ifstream`, which are file based streams. You should use the less specific `ostream` and `istream` instead.